# Projecting revenue using information on percentile?

Tags: python, analysis, prediction, finance, percentile

Suppose I have 2 datasets: splitA (the control group) and another dataset, splitB (the treatment group in which a feature was implemented). Both datasets have the following columns:

username,
session, 
revenue

It was determined for the previous year that August was in the 70th-percentile for revenue. How do I use this information to project the change in annual revenue after implementing the feature?

My calculations thus far:

August was the 70th percentile for revenue last year, so

```
total_revenue_A_aug = np.sum(splitA_df.revenue)
std_a = np.std(splitA_df.revenue)
```

Follows standard normal distribution X = mu + z*sigma...

```
mean_A = total_revenue_A_aug - 0.5244*std_a
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is less about programming and more about data analysis

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are kind of on track but there is a lot missing. Let's assume the months follow a normal distribution. You can pick a different one, the principle still applies. Anyway, first calculate the monthly average for the first year:

```
Mean_revenue_A = np.sum(splitA.revenue)/12.0 # assuming you have 12 months in both data sets
```

Then get the standard deviation:

```
std_a = np.std(splitA.revenue)
```

Finally, get the value of the 70th percentile this year:

```
import scipy.stats as s
# 70th percentile
percentile = s.norm(0,1).ppf(.7)
projection = Mean_revenue_A + percentile*std_a
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. What do I do with splitB (the treatment data)?

Comment: @RileyHun since you already know the percentile for that month, you don't really need to do anything with it. You could use it to analyze the distribution and see if the Normal distribution is really a good fit.

Comment: Each of the datasets only cover the month of August, not the entire year. So I'm confused by your calculations for mean_revenue_A.

Comment: @RileyHun in that case I am very confused by your original question.

Comment: What does this have to do with the 70th percentile?

Comment: "It was determined for the previous year that August was in the 70th-percentile for revenue."

Comment: If you don't have the monthly revenue for this year, there's not a lot you can do. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase...we have a 'revenue' columns for both datasets. What I was trying to say though is that each of these datasets only contains revenue data for the month of August, not the entire year.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127674/discussion-between-riley-hun-and-rofls).

Comment: I plotted a histogram, and looks like the revenue follows lognormal distribution